# Unable to compile Qt using QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, maya, vtable, qglwidget

I am writing a Maya plugin in c++. However whenever I want to use QGLWidget, I receive plenty of vtable errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QGLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)", referenced from:
      vtable for GLWidget in myOpenGLWindowClass.o
  "QGLWidget::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)", referenced from:
      vtable for GLWidget in myOpenGLWindowClass.o
  "QGLWidget::qt_metacast(char const*)", referenced from:
      vtable for GLWidget in myOpenGLWindowClass.o
  "QGLWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)", referenced from:
      vtable for GLWidget in myOpenGLWindowClass.o
  "QGLWidget::paintOverlayGL()", referenced from:
      vtable for GLWidget in myOpenGLWindowClass.o
  "QGLWidget::resizeOverlayGL(int, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for GLWidget in myOpenGLWindowClass.o
  "QGLWidget::updateOverlayGL()", referenced from:
      vtable for GLWidget in myOpenGLWindowClass.
...
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QGLWidget>

class GLWidget :public QGLWidget
{

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~GLWidget(){};
protected:
    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL( int width, int height );
    virtual void paintGL();

};

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{

}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(100,500);
    glVertex2f(500,100);
    glEnd();
}
```

Is there a library I need to add in my compilation or anything else wrong ?

Comment: Please add how you are trying to compile (which compiler, which flags, ...)

Comment: Thanks to your comment I found a missing framework in the compilation (posted the answer). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the QtOpenGL framework in the compilation.

Comment: If you switch to using the newer QOpenGLWidget that would work too, as that is just part of the widgets module.